# Store a list in Erlang ETS

Tags: list, erlang, ets

I am trying to insert a list into ETS to pull out later and for some reason it is saying it is a bad arg. I'm not sure if I'm inserting it incorrectly.

Is it just not possible to insert a list into ETS?

The offending line is `ets:insert(table, [{parsed_file, UUIDs}])`.

Here is the code:

```
readUUID(Id, Props) ->
    fun () -> 
        %%TableBool = proplists:get_value(table_bool, Props, <<"">>),
        [{_, Parsed}] = ets:lookup(table, parsed_bool),
        case Parsed of
          true  ->
            {uuids, UUIDs} = ets:lookup(table, parsed_bool),
            Index = random:uniform(length(UUIDs)),
            list_to_binary(lists:nth(Index, UUIDs));
          false -> 
            [{_, Dir}] = ets:lookup(table, config_dir),
            File = proplists:get_value(uuid_file, Props, <<"">>),
            UUIDs = parse_file(filename:join([Dir, "config", File])),
            ets:insert(table, [{parsed_file, {uuids, UUIDs}}]),
            ets:insert(table, [{parsed_bool, true}]),
            Index = random:uniform(length(UUIDs)),
            list_to_binary(lists:nth(Index, UUIDs))
        end
    end.

parse_file(File) ->
  {ok, Data} = file:read_file(File),
  parse(Data, []).

parse([], Done) ->
  lists:reverse(Done);

parse(Data, Done) ->
  {Line, Rest} = case re:split(Data, "\n", [{return, list}, {parts, 2}]) of
                   [L,R] -> {L,R};
                   [L]   -> {L,[]}
                 end,
  parse(Rest, [Line|Done]).
```

Comment: It works for me... Are you sure that process which calls insert is owner of ets or table is public? I don't see code responsible for creating it. [Check this](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html).

Comment: You should be aware of that can only actually put tuples into an ETS table, not lists. So when you do `ets:insert(table, [...])` you are actually inserting the tuples in the list, **not** the list it self. And when you do `ets:lookup(table, Key)` you are getting back a list of the tuples which have that key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the table in the same proc with something like

```
ets:new(table, [set, named_table, public]).
```

then you should be ok. Default permissions are protected, where only creating process can write.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow on to my comment about ets tables only containing tuples and what `ets:lookup/2` returns the following line in your code:

```
        {uuids, UUIDs} = ets:lookup(table, parsed_bool),
```

**WILL ALWAYS GENERATE AN ERROR** as `ets:lookup/2` returns a list. The call 3 lines above may succeed. It seems like you are trying to do 2 lookups in `table` with key `parsed_bool` and expect to get 2 different types of answers: `{_, Parsed}` and `{uuids, UUIDs}`. Remember that ETS does not provide key-value tables but tables of tuples where one of the elements, default the first, is the key and doing `ets:lookup/2` returns a list of the tuples with that key. How many you can get back depends on the properties of the table.

Check out the documentation of [ETS tables](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html).